# To serialize org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab

Tags: primefaces, java-ee-8

I am getting the following exception when I try to serialize an instance of org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,

"Unable to make field private java.lang.ref.Reference java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.propertyTypeRef accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.beans" to unnamed module @5ea8d39"

I have succesfully serialized each element of the tab, i means its content, one by one. However when i try to serialize the whole tab I get the error.

The code that I use to serialize is:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = null;
try {
    json = gson.toJson(tabs);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("INFO: " + new Date()+ " --> " +json);
```

It is the same code that I use to serialize successfully each child element of the tab.

I should be getting a String with a list of child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF component instances are per spec not serializable, neither PrimeFaces are.
What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I have a SPA and need to serialize the whole page content, not just the session, to store it in redis. That way, when the load balancer process a request no matter what server it assign the request the view is going to be the same.